# What is the advantage of "#!/usr/bin/env python" in the shebang rather than just calling the "#!python" interpreter?

Tags: python, shebang

I understand the difference between starting a python script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

From what I understood, just executes python as we would do in our shell, so it looks in `$PATH`. The second one is not a fixed path, which has the inconvenient that in a different system the python interpreter might be located in another path.

My question is, why do we need `env`? Why can we just do:

```
#!python
```

This works perfectly fine in my computer? Is there a reason to prefer calling `env`?

Comment: what is your computer?
and what do you type to start your script.

At least (if I remember well) when I tried this out last (over 20 years ago ;-) ) this didn't work.

Comment: tried. still doesn't work today on my machine

Comment: It sounds like you may have been running your script in a way that ignores the shebang line, such as `python script.py`, or running it on Windows.

Comment: I would actually prefer *not* to use `env`. Using `env` says to run the script with your *preferred* Python interpreter, which may not be the interpreter the code *requires*. `#!python`, strictly speaking, isn't meant to work as-is. The Python installer (`pip`, `setup.py`, etc) will automatically *replace* that shebang (really, any shebang containing the string `python`; that's just the minimal example of such a one) with a  locally specified absolute path appropriate. That is, it's the job of the installer, not the runner, to make sure the correct interpreter is available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer:**
This depends on the shell. in bash `#!python` will just be ignored and you have to use `#!/usr/bin/env python`. `zsh` on the other hand seems to be able to handle `#!python`.

**The long answer (for bash):**

let's imagine your python file is named 'tst.py' 
and has following contents

```
#!python
import sys
print(sys.executable, sys.version)
```

then you can always type

```
python tst.py
```

The first line is completely irrelevant and is not even looked at.

However if you do following (for example on linux)

```
chmod +x tst.py
./tst.py
```

Then the first line is looked at to determine which interpreter shall be used (bash, perl, python, something else?) and here at least for my OS (ubuntu) and my shell (bash) an absolute path is required for the executable name (e.g. `/bin/bash`, `/bin/python`, `/usr/bin/env`)

If I call ./tst.py on my ubuntu machine I get

```
bash: ./tst.py: python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Special case Windows, when typing tst.py or clicking on a python script.
If you're on windows, the line is looked at, but even if it is wrong a default python interpreter will be used. On Windows, this line could be used to select explicitly python2 or python3 for example.
Windows uses file type associations to determine which executable to call for which suffix. for .py files (python 3.x is installed) this is normally py.exe which is an executable located in the system path, that will just call a python interpreter. depending on installed versions, the shebang line and environment vars, that might indicate a virtualenv

Addendum:
The first line is interpreted by the shell or in the windows case by py.exe.

It seems bash requires absolute paths for command, whereas zsh accepts relative paths as well.

So for zsh only

```
#!python
```

works perfectly well whereas bash requiers absolute paths and thus the trick with the env command

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

For scripts that shall be executed by a cronjob it's best to hardcode the path of the python executable as PATH is rather minimalistic for cronjobs, so there it's best to have something like

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
```

or

```
#!/home/username/myvirtualenv/bin/python
```

Comment: Interesting, in arch it finds the relative path just as if I will execute python from my terminal and #!python works for me

Comment: @Blasco Yes Indeed this is interesting. `are you using bash or another shell.
It might not be the OS, but the shell which reacts differently.

Whatever in order to be as interoparable as possible it still seems to be best to use
`#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Makes sense, it's the answer I was looking for, I thought it might work with all shells. I'm using zsh.

Comment: I add this to my answer as answers are more presistent than comments

Answer (score 2):

Each Python script is written with a particular version of Python in mind. If the shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env python`, that puts the version used under the control of the individual *caller*, whose `PATH` may not provide the right version.

`#!/usr/bin/python` is a little better, as it puts the decision in the hands of the script itself. However, the script author doesn't necessarily know where the correction version of Python is on *your* system, so it still may not work.

The solution is to specify the correct location on *your* system when you *install* the module or script. The Python installer (`pip`, etc) will, at that time, *rewrite* any shebang containing the word `python` (`#!python` being the minimal such shebang) to the path specified by the installer.

Now when you run the script, it will point to the correct path that you have already provided, without being subject to runtime PATH lookup that could choose the wrong version.

Note that `#!python` is not meant to be used as-is, though for various reasons it *might* work for you. It's is a means towards making sure the script gets a fixed, absolute path to the correct interpreter. `#!/usr/bin/python` is *also* subject to install-time replacement, so may serve as a usable default.